# How hide column whit DataGridTextColumn in UWP [XAML]?

Tags: xaml, uwp, datagrid, controls

I have a DataGridTextColumn in a page of a project in UWP, use the code of this page. Since UWP does not have a native DataGrid, investigate and find this code open:

https://github.com/RSuter/MyToolkit/wiki/DataGrid

at the moment I have it like this:

```
xmlns: controls = "using: MyToolkit.Controls"

<controls: DataGrid x: Name = "DataGrid" ItemsSource = "{Binding Third Parties}" SelectedItem = "{Binding ThirdSelected, Mode = TwoWay}" DefaultOrderIndex = "0" SelectionMode = "Extended">
    <controls: DataGrid.Columns>
         <controls: DataGridTextColumn Width = "150" Header = "Nit" Binding = "{Binding Nit}" />
         <controls: DataGridTextColumn Width = "300" Header = "Nom1" Binding = "{Binding Nom1}" />
         <controls: DataGridTextColumn Width = "300" Header = "Ape1" Binding = "{Binding Ape1}" />
         <controls: DataGridTextColumn Width = "300" Header = "Name" Binding = "{Binding Name}" />
         <controls: DataGridTextColumn Width = "300" Header = "Tel" Binding = "{Binding Tel}" />
     </controls:DataGrid.Columns>         
</controls: DataGrid>
```

I have several columns of a model called "Person", when I do the query it loads well, but I want the user who is using the program to choose which columns he wants to see.

For that it had occurred to me to use some property of Visibility or IsEnable to the column, but it turns out that it does not have. How can I do it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Since UWP does not have a native DataGrid, ...

The [Windows Community Toolkit](https://github.com/Microsoft/WindowsCommunityToolkit) includes a [DataGrid](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/communitytoolkit/controls/datagrid) control whose columns have an `IsVisible` property that you can set to `true`/`false` as usual.

You can use it in your UWP 10.0.15063.0+ app by installing [this NuGet package](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Toolkit.Uwp.UI.Controls.DataGrid/).

Comment: Okey, Im installing the NuGet package... now how call the "IsVisible" property?

Comment: Just set the property of the column, e.g.: `<controls:DataGridTextColumn IsVisible="True" .../>`